# Como fazer script C# para rodar HTML?

Tags: javascript, c#, html

Eu desenvolvi um script C# (CSharp) voltado a páginas da internet!

Comment: OBS: o nome do arquivo seria downloads.html com o script downloads.html.cs

Comment: Tá falando [asp](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/asp.net/info)?

Comment: Não é somente html (arquivos .html, .htm)

Comment: Em asp/aspx eu sei mas eu queria em html especificamente!

Comment: Acho que em HTML não usa C# Script. Já vi dizer sobre VBscript no Internet Explorer.

Comment: Muito obrigado pensei que teria como usar C# Script em HTML. OK!

Comment: @Tony mas como eu faço para um arquivo .aspx rodar como se fosse html?

Comment: @Tony Eu queria adicionar script externo C# ao meu blog:
http://brasilcfal.blogspot.com por isso eu preciso rodar C# em HTML!

Comment: Tipo isso  <% { Response.Write("<br>" + i.ToString()); }%> ?
mas acho que só funciona no aspx e não em html

Comment: Você poderá tentar usar o WPF ou Silverlight.

Comment: @FRNathan13 eu dei uma resposta agora porque a resposta que você havia aceito e era a única na época já não fazia sentido, agora faz menos ainda, o que eu respondei é a única solução plausível. Você não é obrigado fazer nada, mas se tiver interesse, pode mudar a aceitação se achar que a nova resposta é mais adequada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode tentar usar o Script#, http://scriptsharp.com/, um compilador que converte .Net para JavaScript.

Não seria ótimo se você pudesse escrever código C# em vez de JavaScript? Isso é possível com o Script# (versão 0.5.1), que se trata de um compilador, um tempo de execução e uma estrutura gratuitos criados por Nikhil Kothari, arquiteto de software da Microsoft. O compilador do Script# pega o código C# e o converte no código JavaScript equivalente.
Use o Script# para criar funções JavaScript curtas e unitárias ou manipuladores de eventos, bem como bibliotecas JavaScript maiores. Você pode usá-lo para criar comportamentos e componentes AJAX ASP.NET ou gadgets da Barra Lateral do Windows Vista. O compilador do Script# pode usar arquivos .resx para gerar arquivos de script localizados e pode ser configurado para gerar scripts de depuração ou de versão. (Os scripts de depuração possuem espaços em branco e nomes de variáveis descritivos para facilitar a leitura, enquanto os scripts de versão têm seus espaços em branco desnecessários removidos e renomeação de variáveis para simplificar a compactação de código.) Resumindo, o Script# proporciona todos os benefícios de trabalhar com código C# – erros em tempo de compilação, familiaridade com a semântica e a sintaxe de OOP no C# e melhor suporte a ferramentas – ao mesmo tempo em que gera o código JavaScript necessário para o aplicativo Web ou os gadgets da Barra Lateral.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/magazine/dd315418.aspx

Ou o JSIL
http://jsil.org/

Apesar de estar sendo abandonado, caso você realmente queira utilizar o **C#** no browser, poderá utilizar o **Silverlight**

http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/

Comment: é que eu tenho bastante conhecimento em C# mas tenho pouco conhecimento em javascript então tem coisas que eu queria fazer em html que seria necessário o javascript mas eu não sei!

Comment: A princípio, o JavaScript não é tão difícil assim. Além disto, você poderá usar ASP.Net e SignalR para se comunicar com seu cliente HTML.

Answer (score 3):

Silverlight é completamente abandonado e não deve ser usado em nenhuma hipótese. Ele já estava não oficialmente abandonado na época da resposta.

JSIL é uma enorme gambiarra, não é para fazer aplicações no *browser*, é só para fazer aplicações rodarem no nele, em situações bem específicas funcionará, e até onde eu sei foi abandonado. Nunca foi adotada pela comunidade, nem mesmo na época da resposta.

Script# e outras soluções do tipo foram abandonadas e eram bem ruins, mal dava para quebrar um galho, era útil na teoria. Também sem adoção antes.

A única solução real, ativa e que tem futuro é o [Blazor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/288706/101). Ele foi feito para o que a pergunta pede e é suportado pela Microsoft. Não é uma gambiarra, é uma solução pensada para isto. Na época não existia ainda.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Isto é correto? Responder uma pergunta de 8 anos atrás? Qual deve ser o procedimento em relação a esta pergunta? olhando em retrocesso sabemos que o Silverlight foi descontinuado. E chegou ao seu fim da vida em 12 de outubro de 2021. Porém não acho correto postar em uma pergunta que possui uma resposta aceita.

Comment: Faça esse questionamento no meta. É correto você positivar uma resposta claramente errada em todos sentidos para prejudicar a minha que é certa? É correto negativar uma resposta correta? Algumas pessoas acham que o correto é fazer errado. Isso está cada vez mais comum aqui. E você está há bastante tempo aqui para saber qual é o objetivo do site, mesmo que não concorde. Aqui é para criar um repositório de informações corretas. Alguém pode achar isso. Você achou e aprendeu errado e escolheu ignorar o certo. aí não posso fazer nada, mas para os outros, tem o certo agora.

Comment: @Danizavtz "*não acho correto postar em uma pergunta que possui uma resposta aceita*" - Não tem problema nenhum, por vários motivos. Pode ser que uma versão nova tenha surgido e agora exista outra solução, pode ser que a resposta aceita esteja obsoleta, tem até casos em que a aceita esteja errada ou tenha problemas. Se a pergunta é antiga ou não, é irrelevante. Eu mesmo [já fiz isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/65404/112052), pois a resposta aceita estava muito ruim

Comment: @Danizavtz Eu fiz: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8831/101

Comment: @hkotsubo, beleza então, eu fui influenciado positivamente pela atitude de vocês, a partir de hoje farei o mesmo.