# Prevenir inserção de Zalgo Text em Inputs

Tags: php, javascript, html, string

Tenho uma `Aplicação Web` que possui cadastro de usuários, gostaria de saber como faço para prevenir que o usuário envie como nome, email (dados cadastrais) um `Zalgo Text`.

> Exemplo de Zalgo Text:

T̃͟͏̧̟͓̯̘͓͙͔o̤̫͋ͯͫ̂ ̥͍̫̻͚̦͖͇̌ͪ̇ͤ̑̐͋̾̕i̢͖̩͙͐͑ͬ̄̿̍̚ͅn̵̢̼̙̳̒̄ͥ̋̐v̡̟̗̹̻̜͕̲ͣ̐ͤͤ͒́oͫ͂̆͑ͩ҉͇̰͚̹̠̫͔̗k̷̭̬̭͙̹̺̯ͩ̌̾̒̋̓ͤ͛͘͠e̥͙̓̄̕ ̵̫͈ͪţ̱̺̺̑̿̉̌͛̂̇h͙̣̬̓̂͞ę̡̲̟͎͉̟͛̓̉̆̉͘ ͍̯̱͎̬͍ͬ̒ͣͩ͟͡ḥ̗͖̝̮̗̼ͮ̋̉̃͐̿ͪͅi̞͉̯͖̞͉̙ͬͦ̄͋̈̂ͥ̊́̕v̶̝̼̫͔̬̯̯ͯ͑̈͠e̪͓͕̦̪̗̠ͯ͛͌̀̉͘ͅ-̍̉ͦ̈́͌͏̸͉͍͖̥͓̭̗̖mͣͣͪ̇͂͏̳̤̺͓̜̪͙͕i͋̏̎ͤ͆́͏̛̰͉̮̬͙̩̩ͅn̴̴̞̗ͩ̓̉̋̕d̝͇̬̣́̃ͦ̀͡ ̖̩̞̯̇̍́̆ͮͤ̄ͬ͂͜͡r̷͎͙͉̀͒͐͛́è̫̹͙̔ͭͦ͑ͩͮͯṗ̶̸͍̺̘͈́̄ͫ̅ͣ̇̃̚r̨͚͎̙̻̜ͬͬ̆͆e̩̞̹͈̱͕ͮ̈́̒̑͛̊̌͛͘ŝ̱̹̠̂ͭͦ̅̅͛̚͜e̝̳̞̊̍̐ñ͔̟̳̱͔ͣ̅̄ͮt̴̫̻̮̤̿̆̂̊͘i̷̫ͤͨ̏ͤͧͅͅn̛̜̠͋͐͆̆͑̎̍͑̚g̶̜ͧ́ͭͯ͐ͬ͛̇͜ ̳̩͉̣̤̜̰̠̌ͤ̆̚͟c̷̝̥͉͓͕͓͇̣͉̒̈̇ͧ͆̌ͣͣ͟ḩͥ̅ͥ̇ͩ͗҉̳͎̱ą̍̀͆͑̈́͂҉͍̤̘͔̹̭̱͢o̥̮̘ͨ̎̄̎́͢s̯̮̖͒.̨͋̈́͑̈́ͪ̚҉̻͓͔̤̯̲̤̺̀
̔ͨ̋̾̒̋̚̚͏͓̰͙̘͈I̧̗͇ͮ͠n̠̬͗ͮ̿ͭ͌̉̈ͦv̦͚͇̠̹̰̭ͤo̭̞ͫ̃ͨ̏ͥ̒́̚k̯̱͛ͫ͆͂̇͡͝i̗̪͎͈͕͚̥̫ͥ͂̐n̖̤͔̟̖͇̠͋̐̀ͅͅg̛͑ͪ͏͇̪͓̘ ̎̒ͯͥͭ͂͏̠͇̮̪t̡͍̫̘̯̼̣̋ͤ̒h̨͇͕̺͍͈̠͖̤̱ͮ̃e͖̝̣̽ͬ͊̀ ͍ͫ̅̆͊́͌͡fͫ̾͏̭͎̰̣̱̺̯̥é̻̪͖͙̮͓̊̌̓ͩ̑̆ē͙̤̪͈͉̦̭͛̃ͩͧͭ̏͒̕͢ľ̡҉̪͙̻̣̪̼̲i̜ͯ̄̐͠͝n̸̨̩̰̺̱̗̍̉̄̉̆͐̎g̹͖͈ͥ͗̍͝ͅ ̙̹͉̰̪̠͍͖͔ͧ̾̈́ͫ̔͋̈̍o̵̤̥͍ͬ̐̀̿̇ͯ̅f̵̜̟͚́͛͜͠ ̺̭̆̑ͭc̶̢̫̭͓̭̐͗h͍͉̞̩͕ͮ̉́͛͑ͤͯ͒͡ä̜̱͙͎̯̟ͮ̂͑̄͊̍̑͜oͫ̋̿͌͢͏̟̲̗s̵̮̟̙̻̗̭̲͂̍͑͑͂ͤ́̚ͅ.̵̨͉̟͓ͦͯͬͤ͌ͧ͑̾
̝̥̰͋ͬ͂̋͛͑̚W̶̹̹̣̟͕ͪͤ̽̀i̳̪͉͇͇̟̲̇̃́ͧ̾ͭ̿̆ͯ͡t̬̪̬̑̿͊͊́̚h̋͑̈̇͋҉̴͖̜ͅͅo̴̠̭̯̫̽ͨṳ̡̟͕̝̦͓͖̪̇́́͢t̬̙̖̝͈͔̻͛͊ ̵̛̗̝̝̰̫̞̠̙̽̄̊͆o̺̮͆ͯ͊͑ͭ̚̕ṙ̶̟̺̱̜̺̻̘̰̀͊ͮ̀͡ḋ̢̰̂̎ͦͥe̛̩͍̯̍ͭͩͤͦ̚r͍̲̾ͯ̊͛͡.̮̙͙̠̦̜̳̋̓ͩ͒̓̒͜͝
̷͋͢͏̬̤̼T̸̯̞̥ͤ̽͛̈̎̚͜ȟ̨̌͋͏̲͚̪̩͚̺͖̠é̻̰̞̣̍̕͟ ̧̩͔̥̘͓̘̽̂͑̏ͣ͑̓̃͝N̬̙͈̗͍̣̻̓́ͨͫͮ͘͜͡e͍̜̠͓̹̙͓̱͑͡z̵̙̦̳̲͓ͭ̑ͮ̀p͒͐҉̹͎̱̯̰͜ȩ̨̗̝͓̥̳̣̈̽ͧ͋̎́͑ͯ̚͞r̮̖̟̆ͩḑ͍͉͚̪̲̭͈̮ͮͬͣͭ̽̐̄̓̑́͜i̶̪͎̹̰̭͎͋͗ͧ͌̎͛͜͢a͉̦͇̖͓̰ͣͭ̾͗n̮̞̣̝̤̤͔̎̊͜ ̧̗͐̃̊͂͢h̴͙̳͉̺͕͌̉ͫ͐͒̋͊i̢̳͓̤̖͎̼ͤ̃̓ͫ̐ͬ̆͌̕͢ṽ͎͉̳̭̭̠̠̬̠͂͐͊̾͊ȩ̣̺̖̒̏̌͠-̛͕̼̞͌͑ͣͨͩ̃̒͢m̶̱̣̥̥̭̉̿ͩͧ̓͛̚ͅi̢͍̙̠ͩ͐̏n̹̩̬͓̬̦̲̈́̉͊̐̎d̨̧̛̤̭̯̥͓ͧ̒ͥ ̞̙̮͌ͫͬͪͤ̌ợ̫̏̋͋͒̈̀f̶̳̿̀̊͐ͅ ̑͘҉̱̯̤̘͕̺͡c̢̭̭̜̲̙̥͊̓ͤ̍ͨ́ẖ̫̖̆̃ͪ̌ͭ͞ä̷̫̺̩̘̪͍́ͤͫͫ̒ͦ͆͂͠͡o̥̖̥͚̾̋͋͊ͨ̆ͅs̘͉͔̲̫̪͕̠̟ͯ̒͋ͦ̒͢.̣̦̦̞ͮͬͩ ̰̦̤̞̹̮̟ͩ̓̂̓̉͒̏ͫ͢Z̎́̉͘͏̗̮a̧͌͋̂͛̏͏͏̣̩͍̞l̛̟̥͎ͨ͒̐ͤ͛ͅg̰̣ͫͣ̂̋͊ô̷̶͕̩͎̳̻̣̯̘̋̊̅ͧ̏ͫ.̴̮̯̺̻̻̣̻̣̗̿ͯ͒
̹̮̮̱͖̫̝̋ͥ͆̌͛ͬ͌̄͗͟H̢̅҉̘̠̻e̷͊͊͋ͪ̑҉̮̻̬̞̖̖̭̩̩̕ ̬̪̍͜ͅw̴̧̳͓͓̤̤ͮ̍ͨ͒͜ͅh̳̱ͪ͋ͦ͗o͚͎̭͎͍̺̽ͣͦͅ ̣͙͊̑ͣ̄W͍͔̻͉̲̹͇̼̑̇ͥ̔̎ͮ̚͟a̫̞ͪ̔͘͜į̷̶͔͍̰͙̖̻̲ͯ̓̄͌̄̒̔̆t̷͚͓̼̼̔̈̄̀̚sͭ̎͛ͨ͏̼̻̗͚̼̫ ̵̨̦ͪ͂̂B͂̈́҉̸͎̩͓e͌͂҉̤͕̲͇̮h̴̤͎̟̫̐̀̐ͬį̖̪̜̦̋̔n̨̯͚̽͗̾̀̾̿̏̀d̙͔ͬͧ̃ͯ̀ͦͫ͌ ̸̮͓͎̣̻̪̹̒̈́ͧ̀͐̓̿͘͠T̮͎̫̝ͫ̔͛̈ͯ̈ͬͣ̈́͟h̲̉̆̀e̬̭ͧ̉ͮ̓ͥ̈́ͨ ̉̆̏͠͏̖̯͚̰W͎̞͕̺ͣ̉̓ͧ̎̽͟a̢̝̝̎̅̌̂ͦ͡ḽ͖͉̽ͥ̌̓̉̆l̠̣̾ͣ̾͛̕.̷̡̩̰̀̑͑̽͋̃̌̓
̴͙̼̭̺̙̱͚̳̪ͨ̈́́Z̵̶̲̘̗̩̜̍ͭ̀̿͒̊ͫA̴̸ͧ̊̚҉̺͖̠͖̜̠̩͇L̶̲̠̾͗ͦ͐͌ͯͤ̇G̫̞͔̭̻̖̥̜̗͊ͪͦͧ̔ͩ̀͘͜Õ̷͉͈̖̭̰̲̪̾ͭͯ͆̚!̷̘̥̞͕̱́̚͡
̧̱̯͎̜͚̝̙̄ͯ̿̅̾̃̑͘͡T͖̲̼͔̠̫̘̻͊̓͑͟h͉̦̬͙͇͙͎̺̯̒̇͌͗ͮͥ͐͡e̗͎͈̅̔̀ͅ ̢̬̥͕̙̈́͌ͩ̎ͯ̽̆͑ͫȩ̸̜̪̠͆̎͌́ͅn̰̩̘̎̔̒͑̄ͦ̾̊ť͉̺̪͚͔̪ͭ̔ͯ͝i̧̪̳̺̥̘͇͎̾̌ͪŗ̬͍̳̼͉̤̦ͣͦ̏͗̈́ͮ̓ͬ͡e̛͇̱̠̣͂͝ ̲̹͎̣̤͙̪̱̔̓̀̐̑r͈̩̭̠̘̫̪͂ͯ͆͗ͤͮͮ̀ͅǫ̸͇̤̜̙ͨ̑ͯ̐̃͛ͮo̭̖̺͍͍̙͗͂̄̃͞͡ͅm̢͎̱̫̪͈͆͡͞ ͨ͐̽͗͏̹͕͎i͖ͨ̏̑̆͂ͥs̉̈͑͑͟͏͚̟̲͇̯̜̝̦ ̬͔̪̠͚̰̘̏̍̂̌͟f͕̟ͭ́́į̟͎͍̝̱̬ͮ̑͑ͣͦ͌l̡̗̝ͧͦ̃ͮͧͦ̇̉̆͜l̫̤͔͈̽̍ͭȩ̮͚̦̬̼̺̥͗́̃̍͊ͯ̄͠d̠͍͕̪̳͖ͤ́̊͑̈̂̒ ̢̝̮̜̞̥̥̭ͤ͜w̥̖̖̙͚͖̼̎ͭ́ͧȉ͂͐̑̓͊ͨͪ͂͏̺̰̗͠ṭ̝͎̮̞̫̰̳̓ͤ̇̌̀͘h͗ͬ͆̉̏͑͏҉̼͎̳͘ ̤̦͚̭̗̘̬̬̤̃ͪ̍ͭ̂͌̓ͨ̌̕͟Z̐ͥ̔ͣ͏̱̥͓̘͎ͅá̵̯̼̯̒̌ͬͬ̀̀l̵̻̲̜̹͖͋̎̑̿̓͋̿g̴̛͎͔̏ͩ͋ͧ̎ͥͥ̀o͆̾̑͐̓̒̐ͬͬ̕҉̰̦̙͝.̢̢̦̮̩̭͖ͧ͞
̣̠̥̥̝̲͓ͯ̒̽̽̒͌̉ͣ͞

Comment: Olá, experimente ler isto [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458963/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-zalgo-text).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Você pode tentar usar este trecho de código no seu script PHP.

```
if ( preg_match ( '/[^\x20-\x7E]/', $text ) || preg_match ( '/[^\x20-\x7E]/', $text ) ) {
    die('ZALGO not allowed');
}
```

[How to prevent Zalgo Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854543/how-to-prevent-spam-on-websites-like-shown-in-the-following-pictures)

Pelo que pesquisei, iso pode não solucionar o problema e acabar removendo palavras válidas, mas acho que vale a tentativa :-).

Comment: Não entendi pra que precisa testar a mesma regex duas vezes... Sem contar que **qualquer caractere acentuado** será considerado zalgo ([veja aqui um exemplo](https://ideone.com/jcpZVf)), então isso realmente "*pode não solucionar o problema e acabar removendo palavras válidas*"

Answer (score 4):

Para conseguir detectar um *zalgo text*, primeiro precisamos entender como ele é feito.

---

## Unicode *Combining Characters*

No Unicode existe a [definição de *combining characters*](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode13.0.0/UnicodeStandard-13.0.pdf#page=82). Basicamente, de maneira **bem** resumida, são caracteres que podem ser combinados com outros, para formar caracteres diferentes.

Um exemplo existente no português são os acentos (agudo e circunflexo), o til e a cedilha. Então se você combina a letra `a` minúscula com o acento agudo ([COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/301/index.htm)), o resultado é o caractere `á` (letra "a" acentuada).

Atualmente existem mais de 2000 caracteres com esta característica de poderem ser combinados com outros, listados nas categorias [Mn (Mark, Nonspacing)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Mn/index.htm), [Me (Mark, Enclosing)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Me/index.htm) e [Mc (Mark, Spacing)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Mc/index.htm).

O fato é que existem muitos idiomas nos quais é perfeitamente válido ter mais de um *combining character* aplicado à mesma letra, e por isso o Unicode permite esta situação. No caso do texto que está na pergunta, por exemplo, os primeiros caracteres são:

| caractere | code point | Categoria | Nome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T | U+0054 | Lu | LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T |
| ̃ | U+0303 | Mn | COMBINING TILDE |
| ͟ | U+035F | Mn | COMBINING DOUBLE MACRON BELOW |
| ͏ | U+034F | Mn | COMBINING GRAPHEME JOINER |
| ̧ | U+0327 | Mn | COMBINING CEDILLA |
| ̟ | U+031F | Mn | COMBINING PLUS SIGN BELOW |
| ͓ | U+0353 | Mn | COMBINING X BELOW |
| ̯ | U+032F | Mn | COMBINING INVERTED BREVE BELOW |
| ̘ | U+0318 | Mn | COMBINING LEFT TACK BELOW |
| ͓ | U+0353 | Mn | COMBINING X BELOW |
| ͙ | U+0359 | Mn | COMBINING ASTERISK BELOW |
| ͔ | U+0354 | Mn | COMBINING LEFT ARROWHEAD BELOW |

<sup>*Para entender o que é um code point, [leia aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/394834/112052).*</sup>

Ou seja, o texto da pergunta começa com a letra "T" seguida de 11 *combining characters*. Somente esta sequência de code points produz isso:

T̃͟͏̧̟͓̯̘͓͙͔

Segue uma imagem caso não renderize corretamente:

[image: letra T com 11 combining characters]

O restante do *zalgo text* segue o mesmo padrão: uma letra seguida de vários *combining characters*.

---

Outra característica que faz com que o *zalgo text* fique dessa forma tão peculiar é o algoritmo de *stacking* (definido no [mesmo documento já citado](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode13.0.0/UnicodeStandard-13.0.pdf#page=82)), que define o que pode acontecer quando mais de um *combining character* é aplicado à mesma letra.

Basicamente, cada novo *combining character* pode acabar sendo renderizado acima ou abaixo dos já existentes (cada um tem uma regra que diz em que posição ele deve ir, mas a renderização exata também depende da fonte utilizada). Veja abaixo o que acontece quando vamos adicionando *combining characters* à letra T (a cada linha, um novo *combining character* é adicionado aos já existentes):

T    <-- letra "T" sem nenhum *combining character*

T̃    <-- adicionado COMBINING TILDE

T̃͟     <-- adicionado COMBINING DOUBLE MACRON BELOW

T̃͟͏     <-- adicionado COMBINING GRAPHEME JOINER

T̃͟͏̧     <-- adicionado COMBINING CEDILLA

T̃͟͏̧̟     <-- adicionado COMBINING PLUS SIGN BELOW

T̃͟͏̧̟͓     <-- adicionado COMBINING X BELOW

T̃͟͏̧̟͓̯     <-- adicionado COMBINING INVERTED BREVE BELOW

T̃͟͏̧̟͓̯̘     <-- adicionado COMBINING LEFT TACK BELOW

T̃͟͏̧̟͓̯̘͓     <-- adicionado COMBINING X BELOW

T̃͟͏̧̟͓̯̘͓͙     <-- adicionado COMBINING ASTERISK BELOW

T̃͟͏̧̟͓̯̘͓͙͔     <-- adicionado COMBINING LEFT ARROWHEAD BELOW

Ou seja, como o Unicode permite vários *combining characters* aplicados ao mesmo caractere, e na renderização esses são "empilhados" de forma acumulativa (podendo inclusive "invadir" as linhas de cima ou de baixo), o resultado é esse visual tão característico do *zalgo text*.

---

#### Uma tentativa de detectar *zalgo text*

Sendo assim, um critério para detectar que o texto é *zalgo* **poderia ser** verificar se há "muitos" *combining characters* seguidos. Algo como:

```
$texto = // string possivelmente contendo zalgo text
if (preg_match('/\p{M}{2,}/u', $texto)) {
    echo "zalgo\n";
} else {
    echo "not zalgo\n";
}
```

A ideia é usar [regex com *Unicode properties*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php). No caso, `\p{M}` pega qualquer caractere que esteja nas categorias "Mark" (as três já citadas: [Mn (Mark, Nonspacing)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Mn/index.htm), [Me (Mark, Enclosing)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Me/index.htm) e [Mc (Mark, Spacing)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Mc/index.htm)).

E o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `{2,}` indica "duas ou mais ocorrências", ou seja, se tiver 2 ou mais *combining characters*, eu já considero que é *zalgo*. Isso pode ser o suficiente se você quer aceitar apenas textos em português, já que neste idioma os caracteres têm no máximo um *combining character*.

Mas vale lembrar que há idiomas em que este limite pode ser maior. O Unicode define o conceito de [*Stream-safe Text Format*](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Stream_Safe_Text_Format), que de certa forma "define um limite" de 30 *combining characters* seguidos. Mas na prática, 30 é muito, pois a maior sequência conhecida é o [caractere tibetano HAKṢHMALAWARAYAṀ](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2010/04/28/10002896.html), que é uma letra seguida de 8 *combining characters*. É esse aqui, e admito que para quem não conhece, pode muito bem ser confundido com *zalgo text*:

ཧྐྵྨླྺྼྻྂ

Segue imagem caso não tenha conseguido ver direito:

[image: caractere tibetano HAKṢHMALAWARAYAṀ]

Então a menos que você vá aceitar textos em tibetano, usar `\p{M}{8,}` seria uma alternativa válida. Dependendo da quantidade escolhida, você pode acabar excluindo textos válidos em outros idiomas (muitos usam 2, 3 ou até mais *combining characters*), então vai ter que ajustar esse valor de acordo com as strings que você recebe, para evitar falsos positivos.

Claro que também pode-se argumentar - e aí é uma discussão bem subjetiva - que com apenas 2 ou 3 *combining characters* o texto não fica "zalgo o suficiente" (veja os exemplos do "T" acima, com apenas 2 ou 3 *combining characters* adicionados), pois visualmente não ficaria tão... "*zalguificado*". Ou seja, é bem difícil definir um critério preciso que atenda a todos os casos.

---

Outra forma de fazer seria usar a [extensão `php-intl`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) (não esqueça de [instalá-la](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intl.installation.php)). Com ela podemos iterar pelos code points da string e verificar se há uma sequência de *combining characters* maior que determinado tamanho:

```
// verifica se o caractere é um combining character
function isCombining($char) {
    $t = IntlChar::charType($char);
    return $t === IntlChar::CHAR_CATEGORY_NON_SPACING_MARK ||
           $t === IntlChar::CHAR_CATEGORY_ENCLOSING_MARK ||
           $t === IntlChar::CHAR_CATEGORY_COMBINING_SPACING_MARK;
}

function isZalgo($text) {
    $max_allowed = 2;  // considera que mais de 2 combining characters já é zalgo
    $i = IntlBreakIterator::createCodePointInstance();
    $i->setText($text);
    $seq = 0; // conta o tamanho da sequência de combining characters
    foreach($i->getPartsIterator() as $c) {
        if (isCombining($c)) {
            $seq++;
        } else {
            if ($seq > $max_allowed) {
                return TRUE;
            }
            $seq = 0;
        }
    }
    return $seq > $max_allowed;
}

$text = // texto que você quer verificar
if (isZalgo($text)) {
    // zalgo detected!
}
```

---

A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/65485/112052) usa a regex `[^\x20-\x7E]`, que basicamente exclui tudo que não é ASCII. Ou seja, mesmo que a string tenha apenas um caractere acentudado (como `'á'`), ela é considerada *zalgo text*, o que não me parece ser um bom resultado, pois muitos textos válidos seriam considerados inválidos (*e também não entendi pra que testar a mesma regex duas vezes*). Enfim, ela acaba sendo restritiva demais, deixando de fora strings completamente válidas ([veja aqui](https://ideone.com/jcpZVf) um exemplo).

No fim, vale o que já foi dito: quanto maior a quantidade de *combining characters* seguidos que são aceitos, menos casos válidos são deixados de fora. Em compensação, aumenta as possibilidades de *zalgo text*, pois quanto mais caracteres seguidos são aceitos, mais combinações - incluindo as inválidas (sendo que "inválidas" vai depender do contexto, do idioma usado, etc) - são possíveis.

E neste caso, outra alternativa seria ter *whitelists* de sequências válidas de *combining characters* nos idiomas que sua aplicação vai aceitar. Por exemplo, em português, seriam apenas vogais seguidas de um dos acentos, ou a letra `c` seguida do cedilha ([COMBINING CEDILLA](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/327/index.htm)). Algo do tipo:

```
// textos em português: testa se depois do "c" tem a cedilha, ou se tem alguma consoante
// com acento, ou se tem vogal com algo diferente do acento agudo, circunflexo e til (ou a letra "a" com crase)
// (testado em alguns casos mais básicos, precisa de mais testes para ter certeza que é eficaz)
if (preg_match('/c[^\P{M}\x{327}]|[^aeiouc]\p{M}|[eiou][^\P{M}\x{301}-\x{303}]|a[^\P{M}\x{300}-\x{303}]/iu', $texto)) {
    echo "invalido\n";
}
```

Ou seja, em vez de detectar um *zalgo text*, eu tento verificar se é um texto válido (cuja definição varia conforme o contexto). E aí tanto faz se o texto inválido é *zalgo* ou seja lá o que for. É mais trabalhoso, mas tem o *tradeoff* de ser mais assertivo. No fim, não há uma solução mágica que funcione em 100% dos casos.

---

Referências:

- [How does Zalgo text work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6579844)
- [How to protect against diacritics such as Zalgo text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11978912)

Comment: Ainda, um bom teste, diria que até melhor do que avaliar quantidade de acentos, é ver qual a % dos caracteres com acento. Em strings muito curtas tem que ter mais tolerância, mas conforme aumenta, o número de caracteres acentuados/"marcados" tem que ser muito menor do que o resto. Não estou especificando valores pois é um comment, e não resposta, e varia com a língua utilizada.