# O que é ASP.NET Core Blazor?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages, blazor

Vendo a lista de novidades que se encontra no Visual Studio, me deparei com algo falando sobre ASP.NET Core Blazor, e aparentemente não tem quase nada falando sobre, encontrei muito pouco de material, e em inglês, porém mesmo usando o tradutor ficou bem confuso e não consegui saber o que seria isso, muito menos o que faz.

- O que seria esse ASP.NET Core Blazor, qual sua finalidade e o que faz?
- Tem alguma relação com o Razor ou ASP.NET Core Razor Pages? (Nomes semelhantes kkk)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> O que seria esse ASP.NET Core Blazor?

Hoje só chamado de Blazor, é o *engine* que pega seu código em C# e gera um [WebAssemply](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199158/101). Ele permite você usar código C# no seu navegador, desde que seja nas versões mais novas que já suportam WebAssembly (rodará em versões antigas com limitações e baixa performance).

Pelo menos é a forma mais utilizada. Na verdade, ele foi evoluindo e existe um modo que ele faz sem o WebAssembly, pedindo para o servidor entregar certas ações, tudo de forma transparente. E tem experimentos que ele nem precisa rodar em um navegador e usar *bindings* não web. Mas não vou entrar em todos esses detalhes.

Não é que o C# vá rodar no navegador, haverá uma compilação que gerará um código que o navegador entende e executa. De certa forma substitui o JavaScript como linguagem única dos *browsers*, ainda que alguns ainda não tenham entendido que é isso que ocorra na prática (a descrição do projeto diz que ele não substitui o JS, mas não é o que acontece na prática, claro que não mata o JS, é uma alternativa para substituir se a pessoa preferir).

Na verdade, não é só o C#, já que o Blazor pega o [IL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138577/101) para gerar o WebAssembly, então pode ser outras linguagens que compilam para o IL.

Só quero deixar claro que você não pode pegar qualquer código C# e rodará no Chrome, FF, Edge, etc. O código precisa ser escrito pensando em ser rodado lá. A API é quase toda diferente e tem que trabalhar com mais ou menos as mesmas coisas que você trabalha no JS. Mas boa parte do *runtime* está lá para usar, então também não muda tanto assim, mas tem as limitações da plataforma.

Existe uma forma de execução que nem precisa converter o IL para WebAssembly. Apesar de ser menos eficiente tem a vantagem de rodar direto. Isso é possível porque o .NET estará rodando no navegador igual roda em qualquer sistema operacional. Mas acho que não vale a pena detalhar isso nessa pergunta mais geral.

Pode ser especialmente interessante para facilitar o [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101) de validações e outros códigos que devem rodar tanto no servidor quanto no cliente. Ou será útil para quem não quer aprender mais de uma linguagem de programação e já usa C#.

Podemos dizer que é um Angular *killer* :) E React, Vue e outros... Não só ele, mas "todas" as linguagens estão embarcando nos navegadores para competir com JS. Digo isso porque o Blazor envolve o mecanismo que transforma C# em WebAssembly e o sistema de rotas e navegação, controle do DOM e tudo isso que esses *frameworks* possuem. Claro que no início ele não é tão maduro, mas está evoluindo rápido e já tem até algumas inovações, além de ter aprendido com os erros do que já existe.

> Tem alguma relação com o Razor ou ASP.NET Core Razor Pages?

Não diretamente, mas indiretamente claro que tem. O Razor é para montar a página no servidor, então só o HTML é criado, nada da página desenhado ou executado. O Blazor é para o *frontend*, ele executa no navegador, falando grosso modo. Ele usa o mesmo mecanismo para renderizar a página no *frontend*.

Importante que Blazor existe também no lado do servidor então funciona basicamente o mesmo *engine* mas que não gera WebAssembly e é usado para os casos onde o cliente não tem essa capacidade, pra SEO e algum outro motivo que gerar a página no servidor é melhor, usando basicamente o mesmo código.

## Segurança

Não foi perguntado, mas muita gente tem dúvida. A segurança é a mesma do JS, ele não é capaz de fazer nada a mais no navegador padrão que o JS pode. Ele só faz mais rápido e tem bibliotecas mais poderosas, mas não sair criando processos, apagar arquivos ou qualquer coisa que o JS não pode, sem autorização.

Agora não tem mais o Core no nome.

## Versões recentes

Com o tempo o Blazor evoluiu e se consolidou. Algumas pessoas ainda torcem o nariz, e ele não teve uma adesão maciça, mas está com algum mercado.

Em versões recentes resolveram alguns problemas, por exemplo a questão do tempo de carga do wasm. Agora ele pode carregar a versão *server* que tem o *front* extremamente pequeno, mas tem mais latência, não tem a melhor velocidade e produz carga no servidor, mas funciona onde não aceita wasm e é melhor para SEO. Depois, se puder ele vai carregando o wasm, resolvendo esses problemas sem fazer a pessoa esperar a carga total do *runtime*.

Também estão começando explorar as novas funcionalidades que estão sendo disponibilizadas pelos navegadores, por exemplo o *garbage collector* e *threads*.

Ele ainda não é uma panaceia, mas tem casos de uso.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: O "Ele só faz mais rápido", é quase um mito. O overhead que existe do FFI entre o JS <-> WASM mata qualquer performance, e na maioria dos casos o WASM gerado pelo C# é consideramente o mais lento (e maior em tamanho, aumentando ainda mais o loading-time) de todos que já comparei. Obvio, pode considerar que "tem bibliotecas mais poderosas", mas depende do caso de uso. O problema é tão grande, que o Blazor nem sequer carrega no smartphone low-end. E se pesquisar por "performance" no Github, que acha vários casos similares. Eu achava a performance do Go sofrivel, até ver o quão ruim é Blazor.

Comment: Existe um pouco de mito nisso. O ganho é considerável em muitas coisas. Claro que se fica o tempo todo manipulando o DOM e fazendo pouca coisa além disso pode ser ruim. O WASM não está pronto, e está lento em sua evolução, coisas de design by comitê, ainda vai melhorar. O que sabe do LLVM no .NET (postado no meta) pra rodar no browser? O que eu sei é que ele está mais lento que o .NET padrão em quase tudo, e ele não tem nada de especial para contornar a limitação do WASM, ou seja, por que ele seria mais rápido? Não tenho acompanhado sua (in(evolução).

Comment: O problema é que com o Blazor, "incentiva" a manipulação de DOM, indiretamente. Além da manipulação de texto dentro do WASM, num ambiente onde não há como liberar memoria, e o GC é single-thread. Somado a isso, o C#, mesmo com AOT, não elimina código não-usado, ou seja: tanto o Blazor quanto o Swiftwasm ficam facilmente com 30MB+, enquanto Zig/C com seus 500KB, ou o Go com 5MB, que já achava muito. O Blazor ainda faz muito processamento no init, usando muita memoria, mais de 1GB, o que crasha em smartphone.

Comment: O native-llvm não resolve todos os problemas, mas resolve alguns deles, principalmente quando o interesse é usar o C# para processar dados (e não para exibir um website...), o que acontece mais frequentemente no WASI (nos chamados "edge computing"). Mas, ainda estou a espera do compilador [Burst](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.burst@1.2/manual/index.html) se tornar open-source, dai acho que teriamos o melhor compilador de C# -> WASM, 
 já que o Burst não tem o runtime do ASP/C# e também usa LLVM. O problema é que Unity não parece querer tornar open-source. 

Comment: Entendi, o problema é mais de memória então. Isso é complicado mesmo. Eu não acho o Blazor, a solução pra tudo. Na verdade, não acho a web solução pra quase nada.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET Core Blazor é uma evolução do ASP.NET, projetada para simplificar o desenvolvimento de aplicativos web modernos. Blazor é uma palavra que combina "Browser" (navegador) e "Razor" (um mecanismo de marcação do ASP.NET).

A característica mais notável do Blazor é a capacidade de criar aplicativos web interativos usando C# e .NET, tanto no lado do cliente quanto no lado do servidor. Existem duas principais abordagens no Blazor:

**Blazor Server:** Nesta abordagem, a maior parte da lógica de aplicativo é executada no servidor e as atualizações de interface do usuário são transmitidas para o cliente usando SignalR, uma biblioteca em tempo real da Microsoft. Isso permite a criação de aplicativos web responsivos e interativos com a sensação de aplicativos de página única (SPA) sem a complexidade do JavaScript.

**Blazor WebAssembly:** Nesta abordagem, o código C# e .NET é executado diretamente no navegador do cliente usando WebAssembly. Isso permite que você crie aplicativos web completamente do lado do cliente sem a necessidade de um servidor de back-end para lógica de aplicativo. Os aplicativos WebAssembly são executados em um ambiente sandboxed no navegador para garantir a segurança.

Além disso, o Blazor utiliza o modelo de programação Razor, que é uma sintaxe de marcação que combina HTML e C#. Isso permite que os desenvolvedores criem componentes reutilizáveis e mantenham uma estrutura de código limpa e organizada.

Algumas das principais características do ASP.NET Core Blazor incluem:

`Componentização:` Você pode criar componentes reutilizáveis que podem ser usados em todo o aplicativo.
`Data Binding:` Facilita a ligação de dados entre componentes e a interface do usuário.
`Integração com .NET:` Você pode aproveitar as bibliotecas e ferramentas .NET existentes.
Suporte para autenticação e autorização.
`Integração de JavaScript:` É possível integrar código JavaScript em aplicativos Blazor quando necessário.
Suporte a Blazor WebAssembly em navegadores modernos.
Em resumo, o Blazor é uma tecnologia poderosa que permite o desenvolvimento de aplicativos web modernos usando .NET, proporcionando uma experiência de desenvolvimento familiar para os desenvolvedores que já estão acostumados com C# e .NET.

Answer (score -3):

De acordo com a documentação do projeto:

Blazor uses only the latest web standards. No plugins or transpilation needed. It runs in the browser on a real .NET runtime (Mono) implemented in WebAssembly that executes normal .NET assemblies. It works in older browsers too by falling back to an asm.js based .NET runtime.

ou seja, eles implementaram o .net em WebAssembly e assim seus programas em .net rodarão no browser. Em um projeto gerado com Blazor a dll resultante (seu assembly) é carregado no browser e executado.

Mais detalhes veja em https://github.com/aspnet/blazor