# Webview é útil para usar como UI de aplicação?

Tags: mobile, webview, aplicação-desktop, ui

## Contexto

Vi um [artigo do Steve Sanderson falando de um projeto experimental chamado WebWindow](https://blog.stevensanderson.com/2019/11/18/2019-11-18-webwindow-a-cross-platform-webview-for-dotnet-core/) que usa um componente de Webview disponível no sistema operacional para usar como UI de uma aplicação.

Isto tudo tem a ver com o [Blazor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/288706/101) que permite o uso de seu modelo de forma diferentes. Eu acho que entendi as vantagens e desvantagens de cada forma de usar:

[image: Tabela Comparação de UIs com Blazor]
<sub>Clique nela para ver melhor</sub>

```html
1 Servidor impõe penalidade. O WebAssembly é sempre inferior ao nativo para sua aplicação, mas o que mais importa é a UI   
2 Só por causa da UI. O ideal seria ter parâmetros mais precisos   
3 Carga inicial do *runtime*. Fora a aplicação em si. Dados bem aproximados. Server: fica maior que 0 se usar Angular, React, etc.   
4 Aqui é sobre a carga para uso e não o primeiro uso que depende de baixar algo. Server: as trocas de página são lentas. Tem tecnologia que não é tão baixo assim e pode ser maior que web em alguns casos   
5 Se precisa de alguma ação do usuário entre ele chegar onde tem a aplicação e começar usar (não é sobre precisar de um instalador)   
6 Se você decide quando o renderizador final (gráfico) muda a versão e possivelmente cria falhas na aplicação. O SO pode mudar algo, mas é raro quebrar compatibilidade, web não é assim, ainda que melhorou   
7 Problemas diferentes em cada um, pode faltar componente ou não ser na versão desejada e executar algum um pouco diferente do esperado, até falhar, em alguns casos por ação indevida do usuário   
8 Como se parece e interage? Fica como é a plataforma base que está rodando? Web já é meio padronizado, próprio não. Nativo é bom pra plataforma, mas não ajuda quem usa mais de uma   
9 Usa de forma simples e sem sobressaltos? Faz tudo o que deve fazer sem perceber nada esquisito, demoras, ou gerar algum mínimo desconforto comparando com outras opções (por exemplo poder cometer erros porque tem controle sobre o que não é bem sua aplicação, ex.: navegação do browser)   
10 Minha percepção da satisfação do usuário usando (não confio na opinião dele, ele se engana quando comenta sobre, é quase subliminar)   
11 O usuário tem que tomar algum cuidado? Ele pode causar problema na hora de começar usar ou depois fazer algo errado, precisa de esforço adicional para atualizar, por parte do usuário ou do programador? Tem facilidade de manter tudo protegido (um só arquivo)?   
12 Por busca ou canal próprio de divulgação sempre dá por padrão. Estou desconsiderando que a Play Store não serve pra divulgar nada e fora a App Store as outras quase não são usadas   
13 A UI roda no Windows, Android, iOS, Linux, MacOS sem grandes alterações?   
14 Dá muito trabalho para fazer o código se comportar bem em todas plataformas que ele roda? Nativo: Considerando que cada plataforma tem uma base de código e uma não atrapalha a outra   
15 Se usa HTML/CSS ou outra forma (XAML, código, etc.)   
16 Se tem acesso nativo ao OS roda direto na API do SO ou tem alguma camada entre ela   
17 Aqui vai além da UI, dá para acessar qualquer recurso da máquina? Fazer cache? Comunicar por protocolo mais eficiente que HTTP?   
18 É fácil modelar e estilizar a UI? Ou seja, tem que mexer com CSS? :) Ou como dizem "responsivo" argh. Lida bem com mudança de orientação (Isso vale mais pra mobile, mas em certa medida desktop também porque não é só sobre orientação, se ele se vira sozinho quando "o formato da tela" muda)   
19 Dentro do normal que se faz precisa atualizar a aplicação quando muda a composição da UI ou é possível trocar sem mexer na aplicação. Pode contornar dificuldades de atualização com Store. Claro que é possível dar dinamismo em qualquer caso, mas alguns não é comum e depende de esforço extra   
20 Depende de conexão de internet para funcionar? Desde que faça algum sentido a aplicação rodar isolada   
21 Para aplicação não costuma importar, mas não deixa de ser um critério a ser pesado se for necessário   
22 Como é estruturado e manipulado o DOM ou algo semelhante que controla o layout   
23 Isso tem a ver principalmente com tempo, mas também pode envolver outras variáveis como custo do profissional ou infra necessária   
24 Se é fácil mexer depois de pronto? Tem muito caso que depois vira um drama arrumar mesmo que seja "fácil" fazer. Se tem que arrumar coisas por culpa do modelo adotado na tecnologia escolhida   
25 Cada modelo impõe uma forma de debugar o código e tem melhores ou piores ferramentas   
26 Minha percepção do que a comunidade usa e sustenta, principalmente mantendo a tecnologia fresca. Não é só documentação, qualquer coisa que ajude o desenvolvimento   
27 Minha percepção da quantidade e qualidade dos profissionais trabalhando com isso (não estou olhando proporção)   
28    
   
Server: SSR, a renderização do layout é no servidor e o gráfico visível é no cliente   
Browser: WebAssembly com .NET   
PWA: O mesmo com alguns detalhes extras para habilitar esta tecnologia   
Desktop: Electron   
Webview: Novo WebWindow (link do Sanderson)   
Nativo: Blazor experimental que abstrai a UI nativa do OS (provavelmente)   
OS Nativo: WinForms, WPF, WinUI, GTK, Xamarin, etc.   
Abstração do nativo: Eto Forms, Xamarin Forms, Uno, etc.   
Renderização própria: Avalonia...   
   
O que tem "talvez" é que depende de algum esforço próprio ou dependência.

"varia" depende de onde está rodando. Alguns casos talvez fosse melhor separar por tecnologia ou modelo específico, mas ficaria uma tabela muito grande e o foco é Blazor.

O "?" é que não se tem informação suficiente.
   
Não tome a tabela como correta.
   
Só considere a UI e a capacidade de ir além, mas não como vai além, especialmente em pontos como performance (não importa o resto do processamento.
   
Não considerei o fato de algumas formas destas não estarem prontas e até podem não se tornar produtos viáveis, minha visão é para longo prazo. Considerei tecnologias base disponíveis para o sistema operacional para uso com C#.
   
Note que usar C# (quando o Blazor pronto) no lugar de JS é teme muito mais performance, mas não sei bem o quanto. Poderia ter comparado com outras tecnologias, mas meu foco é este.
   
Não estou considerando o uso para aplicações muito complexas e de alta necessidade, só para uso mais normal de aplicativos comuns.
```

Desculpe o abuso do *snippet*, mas achei melhor assim.

Para quem não conhece o Blazor é só o modelo de programação e ele não cuida da renderização final. Ele pode estruturar como as telas serão montadas mas não faz esse trabalho que é feito sempre pelo componente igual ao do navegador ou componente do sistema operacional.

## A pergunta

Minha dúvida é em relação à Webview que existe há algum tempo (não é sobre o Blazor, apenas sobre a decisão de usá-la nele), Já vi críticas e elogios, e por tudo que li parece ser daquelas tecnologias que as pessoas adoram ou odeiam.

Parece que esta técnica está proliferando (não é mais um uso só em mobile e principalmente parece que está deixando de ser pontual).

Eu até vi na [documentação do Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView), que parece ter popularizado a técnica, dizendo que ela não é tão recomendada assim:

> In most cases, we recommend using a standard web browser, like Chrome, to deliver content to the user

Não só isso, já vi muitos debates sobre o assunto, mas alguns admitem que no passado era pior e foi melhorando.

Não falo de usar a Webview para algo pontual quando seria complicado ou impossível fazer diferente, falo de usar como UI principal e até única da sua aplicação. Também não falo da questão geral que eu acho que já ajudei com a tabela acima. Por isso a pergunta é para quem tem experiência usando Webview desta forma e consegue dizer algo fundamentado nessa experiência sobre o uso específico.

**A Webview em si tem algum problema em ser usada como UI da aplicação?**

E ainda, **vê algum problema na abordagem que o artigo *linkado* acima mostra que será usada?**

Não é fundamental para a pergunta mas tem algum ponto sobre WebView da tabela que mereça uma especificação melhor dentro do contexto da pergunta? Por exemplo sobre a performance, pode ser verdade, mas é uma diferença significativa?

Há algo na tabela em relação à WebView que não seja verdade, ainda que tenha sido um dia? (só se ajudar o contexto da pergunta).

Uma resposta equilibrada sem tender para um lado, se for possível, tem mais valor. Em geral tecnologias não possuem só vantagens ou só desvantagens.

*Disclaimer*: eu acho errado usar web como UI de qualquer coisa que não seja casual ou pontual, só quero entender melhor, até para suavizar minha posição, se for o caso.

Comment: cara, eu usei WebView quando isso começou a muitos anos atraz, Hoje eu faço a aplicação no formato PWA -> TWA, sei que requer que o celular do cliente possua um navegador compatível com PWA, mas, analisando as métricas de acesso de um App mobile, quem não usa o Chome? é raro até em iPhone, não sou desenvolvedor de Android, já trabalhei com ele mas não vi motivos extremos para não fazer em formato Web e hoje como PWA -> TWA estão muito bons, não vi por que aprender, sei das limitações de não ter um nativo mas é apenas o meu ponto de vista, a aplicação do AME digital poderia ser simplesmente PWA

Comment: @flourigh o chrome pra iPhone nao usa o mesmo engine, ele é praticamente uma "skin" do WebKit. PWA no iOS ainda é problemático (e pelo que "dizem por aí", a Apple quer assim).

Comment: sim de fato, um exemplo é que não tem o banner no iPhone porém o botão de adicionar a tela inicial funciona praticamente igual

Comment: Quem negativou poderia dar um feedback pra eu melhorar, né? Dá para perceber que teve muito esforço de pesquisa? Uma resposta aqui não ensina muita coisa pra muita gente? Não é uma informação boa para a comunidade? O negativo existe para essas duas coisas. Se a pessoa está negativando por outros motivos está usando o recurso de forma errada.

Comment: É muito comum usar WebView para mostrar um texto de ajuda, por exemplo, porque todo mundo sabe formatar HTML, enquanto um rich text pode ser mais complicado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu vou me focar em duas coisas, porque me parece que o problema todo é sobre isto:

- Como estão as webViews em geral
- WebWindow e as plataformas e aonde "está"

---

### Como estão as webViews em geral

Tive experiência com Webkit2, com MacOS (Cocoa), com WebKitGTK, com Chromium e até com um certo "falecido" pacote do Java que lhe permitia ter um "navegador Mozilla" em sua aplicação (este não falarei, porque este nem cabe aqui e realmente creio que ninguém mais usa a muito tempo) e lhe adianto que todos eu tive algum tipo de problema, não com renderização (em alguns casos sim), mas também não tão graves ao ponto de dizer que não seriam interessantes para uso.

O ponto que o Webkit (GTK também) e Chromium chegaram devo dizer que para gerar coisas visuais no geral não tive problemas, mas admito uma coisinha ou outra, que foram mínimas eu tive alguns problemas, mas creio que tudo isto foram BUGs que já passaram, outros problemas incrivelmente eram mal uso do HTML+css por certas pessoas que funcionavam (quando não deviam) e falhavam no Webkit (e MacOS geralmente), na época era mais fácil acusar o sistema operacional do que admitir que algo estava nas coxas do lado do dev responsável por uma "página X".

Quero dizer que esta "ideia" não é algo tão original, claro que estou "olhando por cima" e posso estar confundindo algo, mas o conceito em si parece que não é algo novo, um exemplo [**`javafx.scene.web.WebView`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html), claro que estou citando só como exemplo mesmo.

O que parece que o WebWindow exigirá um certo suporte do sistema operacional, ou seja somente sistemas operacionais **muito atuais** terão suporte sobre a aplicação e assim como o IE tinha suporte é provável que será semelhante a isto que o Edge-Chromium no Windows10 (no repositório não vi qualquer detalhe razoável sobre isto, creio que dependa disto ainda https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/) será algo como o `Web View` (MacOS 10.3 até 10.14, obsoleto) e `WKWebView` (MacOS 10.10+) e na maioria dos Linux populares provavelmente irá instalar o pacote do `WebkitGTK` e claro isto terá que existir nos repositórios do distro escolhido.

### Possíveis "problemas" no artigo "Steve Sanderson"

Eu não estou afirmando que tem problemas no artigo, ele aborda o que é necessário, mas ele mesmo afirma um possível problema:

> *Caution: This library is super-pre-alpha quality. If you’re thinking of building something real with this, see the notes at the end of this post. So far, this is just another prototype.*

Houve um exagero "super-pre-alpha" para justificar a qualidade e devo dizer que os experimentos sobre isto tudo ainda são "obscuros", claro que admito que o repositório ter chegado a mais de 800 estrelas em 33 dias de existência no Github (entendo que já existia a versão `0.0.1` antes, mas está meio obscuro) é um bom sinal para testes e apontamentos de BUGs e apesar do autor ter deixado claro:

> Currently I’m not making any promises! It’s best to think of it as yet another experiment for now. It’s possible that if enough other people want to get involved, it would be possible to create a proper open-source community project.

Isto é só um experimento e até acho que o apoio da comunidade possa ajudar, mas muitas coisas vem e vão, mas acho que é muito cedo para ter certeza de até aonde isto pode chegar, claro que "relativa vantagem" de poder "portar" (em partes) entre outros "híbridos".

### Problemas além do UI

O maior problema que vejo nos webViews nem é a renderização, porque imagino que a maior parte da preocupação destas novas APIs e frameworks ou metodologias seja sempre atender os sistemas mais novos e as pessoas vão usar essas coisas "novas" achando que vão fazer milagre e se deparam com a barreiras como framework, api, metodologia, etc que:

- Falta de suporte para interagir (se comunicar) com funções externas diretamente dentro da API
- Não funcionam em sistemas anteriores (tanto UI quanto interagir com funções externas)

Claro dá pra dizer sempre que o objetivo é funcionar no mais moderno e sempre vai ter uma alguém dizendo "que se dane os sistemas antigos" ou dizendo "ninguém mais usa tal sistema", até pegar um cliente ou uma série de usuários reclamando por não ser possível instalar ou porque algo não funciona como o esperado.

Existe também o problema do CORs e até certo níveis de segurança, é claro que se a pessoa souber o básico disto em "web" não vai chegar a precisar "controlar" isto, mas volta e meia a falta de conhecimento faz com que muitos pseudos-programadores caiam em uma série de problemas relacionados a segurança, até mesmo "injeção" de algo.

Outro problema que vai além disto tudo (ou seja inclui tudo que foi dito e vai além) são os mobiles, em minha experiência com Android principalmente, algo sempre falha, por exemplo, costumo usar SVG para todos meus apps híbridos, principalmente como background, mas nisto até celulares que eventualmente pareciam modernos rodam um sistema de webView limitado, do qual SVG funciona com `<img>` e `<object>`, mas não funciona para background, e claro que o desenvolvedor provavelmente nem irá se atentar a isto, até a hora de ir para produção.

Estou citando apenas um problema, mas se começar a lembrar até mesmo em Android 4.4, que as pessoas consideram o **mínimo necessário** para se trabalhar me deparei com um ou outro comportamento falho.

E vale lembrar que somando a tudo isto em mobiles existe um grande problema, eventualmente web e webviews são "otimizados" para comportamentos necessários em mobile, exemplos de situações em iOS:

- "highlights" que só existem neste sistema
- o scroll continua a rolar para além do limite acima ou abaixo (e na horizontal também) no "body"
- Algumas propagações de eventos que funcionam em Android eventualmente não funcionam em iOS, como aplicar `document.addEventListener("input", () => {})` e notar que ele não dispara em inputs e textareas, no entanto keyup sim (este não é o único exemplo de problema)

Eu não estou dizendo que são problemas, mas se o comportamento é esperado em um ambiente e o dev entende é ok, mas na maioria as pessoas se irritam com isto em seus híbridos, é claro que a maioria dos "frameworks" resolve isto no CSS, mas não estou falando de frameworks, estou falando apenas do que esperar se vai fazer algo do **"zero"**

---

### Conclusão sobre os webViews e WebWindow

Eu concordo que em toda área de desenvolvimento acabamos nos deparando com "desafios", mas o problema dos webViews, seja mobile, seja desktop, é que terá sempre variações de comportamento inesperadas, na verdade foi raro quando não me deparei com algo assim, então decidir sobre isto "pessoalmente" acho algo arriscado.

Eu também sou do pensamento que os híbridos parecem mais fáceis e que as pessoas estão aderindo a isto e que isto virou uma moda (uma moda que talvez nunca passe) e que os próprios responsáveis por nos influenciar a adotarmos isto também não imaginavam todos problemas que iriam enfrentar e mesmo assim continuaram tentando remendar o que faziam.

Mas eu culpo também os ambientes "desktop" por "falharem", vou pegar o Qt como exemplo apenas. Mesmo de longe acho Qt o melhor do "mercado", no entanto ele é tão cheio de **probleminhas**, a equipe de responsável volta e meia trazia problemas antigos de volta e a plataforma mais usada no mundo é o Windows (e não tô falando dos devs, to falando dos usuários normais/finais) foi aonde mais me deparei com um problemas assim, muita coisa eu acabava tendo que escrever na mão pra resolver, problemas com impressora eram comuns e por incrível que pareça, até o Qt4 era mais limitado, mas funcionava muito bem, já no Qt5, implementaram coisas novas e um processo de correção no bug-report que passado mais alguns updates um bug antigo já corrigido voltava a existir, então se o mais "popular" falhava tanto (não estou dizendo para não usarem, eu aprendi a contornar os problemas) imagine as outras soluções mais simples.

O problema é que para algo popularizar me parece que ele tem que ser um "canivete suíço", coisa que o Qt quase era, mas seus concorrentes não chegavam perto disto.

Eu não estou culpando o Qt, só o peguei de exemplo, eu poderia citar uma série de outros problemas em outros lugares, mas não quero perder o foco, neste ambiente de desenvolvimento Desktop e "zero" compatibilidade entre desenvolvimento mobile é que surgiram coisas como:

- Electron
- Híbridos

Eles dominaram aonde tantos desenvolvedores queriam participar (com ou sem conhecimento sobre o básico), mas não queriam ter trabalho/dificuldade, queriam coisas fáceis e foi nisto que começou a surgir e volta e meia surge coisas como o WebWindow (como já citei, não parece o primeiro caso de tentativa), para tentar "melhorar" o que funciona "mais ou menos", se ele vai "vingar" eu não sei dizer, mas com certeza ele ainda tem muito chão pela frente.

Comment: Teve alguma experiência em mobile? O que andei vendo é pessoas reclamando que eme mobile a Webview costuma ser pior em desempenho de renderização, tem dificuldade de integração com o resto.

Comment: @Maniero editei, talvez eu revise o texto e simplifique, mas adicionar algo a mais creio que não farei, minha visão sobre é esta, webViews são tão problemáticos e causam a falsa ilusão de facilitar, quero dizer, o desenvolvimento é rapido, a correção de incompatibilidades ou descobri-las é que é o problema no final das contas, porque muitas vezes é complicado testar em tudo.